# Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server with credentials defined in .aws folder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a web page on an AWS instance located at `/var/www/html/`

Until now this website used the keys `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in the code itself to access files hosted on S3.
For security reasons,
I have removed these keys from my code and used the `aws configure` command to ssh to store them on the server as recommended by AWS.

I see that in my directory `~.aws/` folder has been created with 2 files: `credentials` and `config`.
Both seem to be correct but in the web logs now I get the following error when trying to access files from S3:

`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (Client error: 'GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials /' resulted in a '404 Not Found resulted in a '404 Not Found' response:`

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- // W3C // DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional // EN"
"http: // www. (truncated ...)
) in /var/www/html/aws/Aws/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php:88
```

I don't know what that URL is but I can't access it through the browser.

I have tried it with environment variables:
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = xxxxx...

I have copied the .aws folder to / var / www
I have given more permissions to .aws, I have changed the owner and group from root to ec2-user ...

**How should I do the configuration so that my code correctly calls S3 and gets the files?**

Call example that fails:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client ([
'version' => 'latest',
'region' => 'eu-central-1'
]);

if ($s3) {
    $result = $ s3-> getObject (array (
                    'Bucket' => AWS_S3_BUCKET,
                    'Key' => $s3_key,
                    'Range' => 'bytes ='. $Startpos .'- '. ($Startpos + 7)
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to move the .aws folder to the home folder of the service (apache) and not your home folder. The aws sdk can't find it and you receive this error. However, it isn't a good idea to use `aws configure` inside an EC2 instance.

The http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ is the meta-data url only available from inside an EC2 instance. For services running in EC2 (or other AWS compute service) you SHOULD NOT use AWS credentials to access services. Instead, you should create an IAM role and add assign it to the instance. From the console, you can do that with the Actions button:

[image: Modify IAM Role]

Only assign required permissions to the role (S3 read/write).

Your code (`$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client`) will try to load the default credentials. It will first try to call the meta-data service and get temporary credentials that correspond to the IAM role permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @kgiannakakis . My Ec2 instance did not have an associated IAM role.
I have created an appropriate one and it works like a charm.

Maybe you could also clarify the following for me:
With the IAM associated with my EC2 I have tried to change aws_access_key_id of the .aws/credentials file (both of the root user and ec2-user) for another erroneous string and it still works fine. How is that possible? It looks like it is taking "other" credentials for the S3 call

Comment: Read here for the priority: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html. It is for Java, but I guess, it would be similar for PHP